# Linux Uniq - identical lines not matching

Tags: uniq

I have a file, asdf2, with four identical lines, that does not get consistent results from the linux uniq command. There is no carriage return in the file, only line feeds.

The file has four lines:

```
$ cat asdf2 | wc -l
4
```

Uniq claims only the first two lines are identical:

```
$ cat asdf2 | uniq -c | wc -l
3
```

Removing a special character makes all lines identical:

```
$ cat asdf2 | sed 's/\xFE//g' | uniq -c | wc -l
1
```

This character is not in the file:

```
$ cat asdf2 | sed 's/\x1C/@/g' | tr -dc '@'
```

Replacing with a different character makes all lines identical:

```
$ cat asdf2 | sed 's/\xFE/\x1C/g' | uniq -c | wc -l
1
```

How can something like this happen?

For concreteness, here is the hex dump:

```
0000000: 506c 616e 6e65 6420 436f 7374 fe41 6374 Planned Cost.Act
0000010: 6976 6974 79fe 4163 7469 7669 7479 2047 ivity.Activity G
0000020: 726f 7570 fe41 6374 6976 6974 7920 4772 roup.Activity Gr
0000030: 6f75 7020 4944 fe41 6374 6976 6974 7920 oup ID.Activity
0000040: 4944 fe41 64fe 4164 2049 44fe 4164 2053 ID.Ad.Ad ID.Ad S
0000050: 7461 7475 73fe 4164 2054 7970 65fe 4164 tatus.Ad Type.Ad
0000060: 7665 7274 6973 6572 fe41 6476 6572 7469 vertiser.Adverti
0000070: 7365 7220 4772 6f75 70fe 4164 7665 7274 ser Group.Advert
0000080: 6973 0a50 6c61 6e6e 6564 2043 6f73 74fe is.Planned Cost.
0000090: 4163 7469 7669 7479 fe41 6374 6976 6974 Activity.Activit
00000a0: 7920 4772 6f75 70fe 4163 7469 7669 7479 y Group.Activity
00000b0: 2047 726f 7570 2049 44fe 4163 7469 7669 Group ID.Activi
00000c0: 7479 2049 44fe 4164 fe41 6420 4944 fe41 ty ID.Ad.Ad ID.A
00000d0: 6420 5374 6174 7573 fe41 6420 5479 7065 d Status.Ad Type
00000e0: fe41 6476 6572 7469 7365 72fe 4164 7665 .Advertiser.Adve
00000f0: 7274 6973 6572 2047 726f 7570 fe41 6476 rtiser Group.Adv
0000100: 6572 7469 730a 506c 616e 6e65 6420 436f ertis.Planned Co
0000110: 7374 fe41 6374 6976 6974 79fe 4163 7469 st.Activity.Acti
0000120: 7669 7479 2047 726f 7570 fe41 6374 6976 vity Group.Activ
0000130: 6974 7920 4772 6f75 7020 4944 fe41 6374 ity Group ID.Act
0000140: 6976 6974 7920 4944 fe41 64fe 4164 2049 ivity ID.Ad.Ad I
0000150: 44fe 4164 2053 7461 7475 73fe 4164 2054 D.Ad Status.Ad T
0000160: 7970 65fe 4164 7665 7274 6973 6572 fe41 ype.Advertiser.A
0000170: 6476 6572 7469 7365 7220 4772 6f75 70fe dvertiser Group.
0000180: 4164 7665 7274 6973 0a50 6c61 6e6e 6564 Advertis.Planned
0000190: 2043 6f73 74fe 4163 7469 7669 7479 fe41 Cost.Activity.A
00001a0: 6374 6976 6974 7920 4772 6f75 70fe 4163 ctivity Group.Ac
00001b0: 7469 7669 7479 2047 726f 7570 2049 44fe tivity Group ID.
00001c0: 4163 7469 7669 7479 2049 44fe 4164 fe41 Activity ID.Ad.A
00001d0: 6420 4944 fe41 6420 5374 6174 7573 fe41 d ID.Ad Status.A
00001e0: 6420 5479 7065 fe41 6476 6572 7469 7365 d Type.Advertise
00001f0: 72fe 4164 7665 7274 6973 6572 2047 726f r.Advertiser Gro
0000200: 7570 fe41 6476 6572 7469 730a up.Advertis.
```

In fact, pasting this directly into the command line seems to work as well:

```
$ echo 'Planned CostþActivityþActivity GroupþActivity Group IDþActivity IDþAdþAd IDþAd StatusþAd TypeþAdvertiserþAdvertiser GroupþAdvertis
Planned CostþActivityþActivity GroupþActivity Group IDþActivity IDþAdþAd IDþAd StatusþAd TypeþAdvertiserþAdvertiser GroupþAdvertis
Planned CostþActivityþActivity GroupþActivity Group IDþActivity IDþAdþAd IDþAd StatusþAd TypeþAdvertiserþAdvertiser GroupþAdvertis
Planned CostþActivityþActivity GroupþActivity Group IDþActivity IDþAdþAd IDþAd StatusþAd TypeþAdvertiserþAdvertiser GroupþAdvertis' | uniq -c | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using GNU `uniq`:

Let's say that I have file `a` that contains:

```
a a
a a
a a
a a
```

#### `uniq a`

```
a a
```

#### `uniq -u a`

```bash
# no output
```

running `uniq a` prints out the first two lines because without any options `uniq` merges matching lines to their *first occurance*.  When you specify `-u`, however, `uniq` *only* prints unique lines.

Read the fine [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) to learn more.

**NOTE**
`uniq` does *not* detect repeated lines *unless* they are adjacent.
You may want to sort the input first, or use `sort -u` without `uniq`.

Comment: I appreciate the information, but I'm not sure you're addressing my question. Did you have a look at the example? This is a section taken out of a file after sorting it, and all four lines are identical. They should reduce to one line.

Comment: Also, the example you give is not correct. When I create the 'a' file and run uniq on it, I get only one line back, not two lines. This is correct behavior for uniq.

Comment: @BlackCarrot weird, maybe I added an extra space or something to one of the lines in file `a` by accident.  Re-ran the `uniq <FILE>` and got the results you just described.